# Error while loading external library Gantii in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, libraries

I'm trying to integrate this to my PHP project: https://github.com/bastianallgeier/gantti

I have copied the calendar.php and gantii.php into application/libraries.

Controller:

```
<?php

class summary extends CI_Controller {

  function index() {
     $this->load->library('gantti');

     $gantti = new Gantti($data, array(
  'title'      => '',
  'cellwidth'  => 25,
  'cellheight' => 35,
  'today'      => true
));

    $this->load->view('summary_view', $gantti);

  }

}
```

View:

```
<?php

require('lib/gantti.php'); 
require('controllers/summary.php'); 

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  

  <title>Summary</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />  

  <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/gantti.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/metro-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Summary</h1>
</div>

<?php echo $gantti ?>

</body>

</html>
```

but instead of viewing the page I receive an error (404) as below:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Missing argument 1 for Gantti::__construct(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\wwww\system\core\Loader.php on line 1099 and defined
Filename: libraries/gantti.php
Line Number: 18

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: data
Filename: libraries/gantti.php
Line Number: 29


A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: libraries/gantti.php
Line Number: 41

Fatal error: Call to a member function month() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\application\libraries\gantti.php on line 58
```

Comment: Please show code for `system\core\Loader.php`.

Comment: Remove `$this->load->library('gantti');`: it doesn't pass arguments to the constructor, but include the class. No need to post the Loader.php code

Comment: @DamienPirsy Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'lib/gantti.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\bit\application\views\summary_view.php on line 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> load->library` to load any library in CI it will automatically call its constructor same thing is happening in this library, but you need to pass at least one parameter to library that's why it is giving error, you can pass only one parameter to library using ci loader

```
$this->load->library('gantti',$data);
```

but you can not set the second parameter for setting to this library but all variables in this library are public you can call them like this to set them

```
$this->gantti->options = array(
  'title'      => '',
  'cellwidth'  => 25,
  'cellheight' => 35,
  'today'      => true
)
```

complete solution

```
$this->load->library('gantti',$data); //first load library and pass data
$this->gantti->options = array(
      'title'      => '',
      'cellwidth'  => 25,
      'cellheight' => 35,
      'today'      => true
    );
$data['gantti'] = $this->gantti->__toString();
```

another solution is create a custom library and extend it with Gantti library copy gantti lib directory under libraries directory

Custom library

```
<?php
    require_once APPPATH.'libraries/lib/gantti.php';

    class cigantti extends Gantti {
        //put your code here

        public function __construct() {
        }

        public function generate($data = array(), $params = array()){
            parent::__construct($data, $params);
            return $this->render();
        }
    }

    ?>
```

in controller

```
$this->load->library('cigantti');
$data['gantti'] = $this->cigantti->generate($data, array(
                    'title' => 'Demo',
                    'cellwidth' => 25,
                    'cellheight' => 35,
                    'today' => true
                ));
```